# Deep linking with Branch.ios not working properly

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I am trying to implement branch.io for deep linking but there are few issues eating up my life. I tried searching up but ending no where.

- Even after setting bundle identifier and team id for universal app linking, app does not get open.
- Setting iOS URI Scheme to some myapp:// does not help.

Comment: Branch has good support.  Use it.  Asking here without giving every single detail of your Branch setup and your app implementation isn't going to work anyway.

Comment: I have setup as per documented in branch.io and generated a marketing url but if i click on that url it takes me to safari instead on opening app already installed on device, where as chrome opens the app.

Comment: As I wrote before, **ask Branch for help**.

Comment: @Avi, Alex from Branch here: thanks very much for your kind words. I'll pass them along to the support folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex from Branch here: it sounds like the Universal Links configuration process hasn't been completed in your app yet. Just setting the Bundle Identifier and Team ID unfortunately isn't quite enough.

Take a look at the full implementation guide [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/overview/) and see if it helps. We would also be happy to see a [support ticket](https://support.branch.io/) since that way we can look into the back end of your account and debug from there too.

Comment: thanks as your support team helped me out with this.

Comment: @ankit.tlp glad to hear it! Let me know if you have any further questions